# Issues with opening a file inside of a function C

Tags: c, function, file-io

Okay so basically the title says it all. I am working on a project where I get a segmentation fault right after I enter the name of the file I want to open. I created a smaller program that did just that, but when I implement it in my project it does not seem to work. I might be overlooking something. Would be awesome if someone could point it out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

//function prototypes
void printmenu();
void getcipher(char **arr, int *count, FILE **infile);

int main()
{
int flag = 1;   //exit flag for menu loop
int choices;    //user input for menu
int count = 0;

char arr[7000][25]; //store words in this array

FILE *infile = NULL;    //input cipher file


while(flag)
{
    printmenu();

    scanf("%d", &choices);
    getchar();


    while(choices < 1 || choices > 4)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input. Try again...");

        scanf("%d", &choices);
        getchar();

    }//end while 

    switch(choices)
    {
        case 1:
            getcipher((char **)arr, &count, &infile);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("2");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("3");
            break;
        case 4:
            flag = 0;
            break;
    }//end switch

}//end while

return 0;

}

void printmenu()
{
printf("\n%s", "Menu Choices");
printf("\n%-40s%-20s", "Use Cipher text file as cipher key", "Enter 1");
printf("\n%-40s%-20s", "Create cipher using a text file","Enter 2");
printf("\n%-40s%-20s", "Decode existing cipher", "Enter 3");
printf("\n%-40s%-20s\n\n", "Exit Program","Enter 4");

}

void getcipher(char **arr, int *count, FILE **infile)
{
int flag;       //flag for getting cipher text file

char buffer[1000];  //buffer for reading in lines

char *token;        

int letters = 0;    //index for letters
int low;        //index for converting to lowercase


//Gets cipher text file
printf("\nEnter the name of the cipher text file: ");
scanf("%s", buffer);

printf("\n%s\n", buffer);

*infile = fopen(buffer, "r");

if(!(*infile))
{
    printf("Unable to open file. Exiting...");
    exit(1);
}//end while

//inputs words from cipher text file to array
while(fgets(buffer, 1000, *infile))
{
    token = strtok(buffer, " ");

    strcat(arr[*count], token);

    count++;

    while((token = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
    {
        strcat(arr[*count], token);

        count++;
    }//end while

}//end while


printf("\n%d" , *count);
int i = 0;
//print array
while(i < *count)
{
    printf("\n%s ", arr[i]);

    i++;
}//end while




}
```

This is my second smaller program that opened a file within a function. I basically copied this into my project.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void openfile(FILE **file);

int main()
{
    FILE *file = NULL;

    openfile(&file);

    return 0;
}

void openfile(FILE **file)
{
    char buffer[100];

    printf("Enter the name of file: ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);

    *file = fopen(buffer, "r");

    if(*file)
        printf("\nSuccess!!");
}
```

Comment: You don't use the file pointer outside the function, but you also don't close the file. Not sure what you are trying to do with using the file like me that.

Comment: You pass a two-dimensional array to a function expecting a `char**`. This is wrong.

Comment: I have more functions to write this is only a small portion of what I wanted to do. This is why I was trying to pass the file by reference. Also, yes, I did forget to close the file but that is irrelevant because I cant even get it open.

Comment: Gonna say this bluntly, John. Unless you *seriously* know what you're doing, if you find yourself casting in C to squelch/hide compiler warnings or errors, you should consider the compiler's warnings/errors gospel, and assume you're doing something wrong. This isn't an exception to that. An array-of-array-of-char is *not* a pointer-to-pointer-to-char.

Comment: Yeah, the parameter for the 2d array should have been ***arr

Comment: @JohnDoe: A pointer is not an array. And something like `type **` cannot represent a 2D array. You should already have been suspicious about a compiler warning you likely casted away. General rule: **only** cast iff 1) The cast is really required **and** 2) You fully understand **all** implications **and** 3) completely accept them. And being a three star programmer is not a compliment in C. Far by most times this is a signal your design is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're casting `arr`, which is `char [7000][25]`, to `char **` when passing it to `getcipher`.  These two declarations are incompatible.  The first is a flat 2-dimensional array, while the second is an array of pointers, each of which points to its own secondary array.  In general, if you are casting one pointer type to another like this, you are probably introducing a bug.

To fix it, you can change your `char **arr` declaration in `getcipher` to `char arr[7000][25]`, or `char arr[][25]`, or `char (*arr)[25]`.  If you don't want to hard-wire the size, you can pass it as a parameter as long as it precedes the array parameter.

Second problem:  You have argument `int *count` in `getcipher`.  In this case it is a pointer to a single `int`.  But you increment it with `count++` in a couple places.  This will increment the pointer, not the integer it points to.  Change it to `(*count)++;`

Comment: Thanks. This would have caused me problems later down the line. I changed the parameters, however i still get a seg fault after i input the name of the file.

Comment: I found a second problem, and edited my answer to include the fix.  See the new last paragraph of my answer.  I actually think you were encountering the first problem I mentioned first, but once fixed, the second problem was exposed.

Comment: It works now after using the contents of operator incrementing the count. Thanks for being patient with me and for the advice as well.